# Jquery File Upload Plugin - Script PHP para copiar Imágenes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fileupload

estoy integrando el plugin jquery file upload plugin y tengo un pequeño problema. Selecciono los ficheros, los copia al servidor, hasta ahí todo bien. El tema es que me da error en el proceso de resize.

En el log del servidor aparece este mensaje:

*[Thu Feb 15 18:44:00.204182 2018] [:error] [pid 14559] [client 192.168.0.184:60853] Function not found: imagecreatetruecolor, referer: https://addcloud.addvantage.es/gestorimatges.php*

El plugin lo inicializo y configuro de la siguiente manera:

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';


    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: 'assets/jquery-file-upload/server/php/index.php',
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(png|jpe?g|tif?f|tif|zip|tar)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 524288000, // 500MB = 524288000Byte
        limitConcurrentUploads: 3,
        disableImageResize: false
    });

    // Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        'redirect',
        window.location.href.replace(
            /\/[^\/]*$/,
            '/cors/result.html?%s'
        )
    );

    if (window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io') {
        // Demo settings:
        $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
            url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
            // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
            // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
            // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
            disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
            maxFileSize: 5000000,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
        });
        // Upload server status check for browsers with CORS support:
        if ($.support.cors) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
                type: 'HEAD'
            }).fail(function () {
                $('<div class="alert alert-danger"/>')
                    .text('Upload server currently unavailable - ' +
                            new Date())
                    .appendTo('#fileupload');
            });
        }
    } else {
        // Load existing files:
        $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
        $.ajax({
            // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
            //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
            url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
            dataType: 'json',
            context: $('#fileupload')[0]
        }).always(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
        }).done(function (result) {
            $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
                .call(this, null, {result: result});
        });
    }

});
```

En definitiva no sé exactamente el porqué realiza un redim de la imagen si le indico la opción a false.

Alguien podría darme alguna ayuda?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no es la redimensión de la imagen a false, suena más bien a que no tienes instalado el modulo GD en PHP, y por eso te produce ese error, ya que quiere crear una nueva imagen a partir de la original.

Haz la siguiente prueba para ver si tienes ese modulo

```
<?php
  $testGD = get_extension_funcs("gd"); 
  if (!$testGD){
      echo "GD no esta instalado.";
      exit;
  }
  echo"<pre>".print_r($testGD,true)."</pre>";
?>
```

Si recibes el mensaje de que no esta instalado, entonces haz lo siguiente

- Crea un archivo y ejecuta un phpinfo() y verifica que ruta tiene extension_dir
- Abre esa ruta en tu computadora, y verifica que este el archivo **php_gd2.dll**
- Si el archivo no esta, tendrás que buscarlo e instalarlo (simplemente un copia y pega en la misma carpeta).
- Una vez instalado, deberás verificar en tu php.ini si existe extension=php_gd2.dll, descomentalo o añadelo.
- Reinicia tu servidor web y tu PHP.
- Vuelve a correr el script de prueba de arriba para ver si se instalo.

Una vez reiniciado, también puedes verlo en tu phpinfo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]